# Forcing HTTPS, along with URL rewriting?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this rule as part of my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^view-([0-9]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This works fine for me, except now I want to add in the following functionality - I want to implement HTTPS for the whole of this directory (this `.htaccess` is inside a directory called `/information/`), except for this one rule - anything that matches for `view-([0-9]+)`. This is what I've got:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/information/view-[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/information/$1 [R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/information/view-[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/information/$1 [R]
```

This is mostly working fine for me, except now when I try to access `http://www.example.com/information/view-101`, it redirects me to `https://www.example.com/information/view.php?id=101`. If I try to access `https://www.example.com/information/view-101`, it also redirects me to the same URL.

I put those six lines on top of the URL rewriting code. All other URLs work fine - for example, `http://www.example.com/information/about` will take me to `https://www.example.com/information/about`, which is the correct functionality - just that one URL seems to take me to the most basic URL form - `view.php?id=101`, disregarding all URL rewriting.

Is there any way this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Remove those 6 lines from the top and write rules like this. Adding below lines at the top of your `.htaccess` file should enforce **`HTTPS`** on all URLs of your domain. It will also redirect `non-www` version of your domain to the `www` version:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.yourdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I need to use HTTP for `view-[0-9]+` URLs - is there any way you can implement that as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/information/view-[0-9]+
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/information/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/information/view-[0-9]+
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/information/view.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/information/$1 [L,R]

RewriteRule ^view-([0-9]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This works, but I don't understand why apache makes external redirect to view.php with code 301.

Comment: yeah, that's what I was wondering as well. In my code it redirects to the `view.php` file, and I can't figure out why.